# How do I export data from Oracle 11.1 to 10.1?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, oracle-11g, export

I have a 11.1 oracle server and I need to export a dump file for a client who has a 10.1 server.

While reading the documentation, I figured out I needed the 10.1 Export Utility. I searched the Oracle site and I couln't find it.

How can I get this utility?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, you'll be wanting to use the 11.1 Data Pump (`expdp`/`impdp`) rather than `exp`/`imp`. With Data Pump you export using the higher version export utility with the `VERSION=` parameter.

For example:

`expdp scott/tiger version=10.1 directory=DUMPDIR dumpfile=DUMPFILE.dmp logfile=DUMP.log`

Don't forget to create the directory (using `CREATE DIRECTORY DUMPDIR AS '/path/to/dir';`) first.

Comment: And my client can import it with his imp.exe utility like a regular dump file?

Comment: No, import with `impdp` - 10.1 was the first version that came with this utility.

Comment: If I have a client with 9.2? Am I in trouble?

Comment: 9.2 is no longer supported.